# Prettier, is it possible to disable for a language?

Tags: vue.js, formatting, prettier

I'm using Prettier with [pretty-quick](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pretty-quick) and do not agree with how it formats HTML. I know I can exclude by globs but can I exclude by language so that the HTML in my Vue files are untouched?

Answer (score 0):

No. It's not possible. HTML is considered the "main language" of a `.vue` file, JS and CSS "embedded". You can only disable formatting for embedded languages by the `--embedded-language-formatting off` option. As for `template` tags, the only way to keep them unformatted is to put `<!--prettier-ignore-->` in front of each of them.